# Solving systems of equations and determining consistency

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am not able to compute the REF or the RREF, the **a** confuses me with the calculations. I do know how to check for consistency and inconsistency but I couldn't perform any row operations due to the presence of **a**

$$\begin{cases}
2_1 + _2 − _3   =  0\\
_1 + 2_2 + _3   =  0\\
−2_2 − 2_3   =  0\\
a_1 + _2 + _3 = 0
\end{cases}$$

a)  For which values of the scalar    is this system consistent and exactly determined?

b)  Solve the system, using the value for    that makes it consistent and undetermined.

Comment: What is the system?

Comment: I've just added the system

Comment: Well, just look at $a$ as any number. For example, it is ok to do the $R_3 \rightarrow R_3 - aR_2$. You just have to be careful when you divide by $a$ or something like $a-x$ for some $x$, because it can be $0$. In that case, you need to check what happens when, for example, $a=0$, and keep on going.